# Standard response to "Amen"?

Tags: minhag, blessing, language

Is there some  sort of standard response to "Amen"? That is, if another says Amen in response to one's blessing.

Comment: Some clarification of context is needed. Amen is itself a response. In what circumstances do you expect this response requires a response? Or if you have no context: add your understanding of what amen means so that an answer may address your understanding of it

Comment: Maybe "Amen" back to them? It means "may it be so..."

Comment: no. [char.....]

Answer (score 1):

I have heard "כן י'הי רצון" -- approximately "would that it were so" -- used in this function (and, otherwise, as a substitute for "Amen").